# Why do I have indexing by the side of my output - Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Pardon this noob question:

1. Why do I have Indexing 0 - 4 by the side? Is there someway that I can remove?
2. Also, I am not sure how can I remove the display of the type even though I don't think I have specified it in my code below?

I am using `Python Pandas` and the following is what I have coded. Thanks! :)

```
# By Flat Price
min_flat_price = float(input ("Enter a minimum flat price: "))
max_flat_price = float(input ("Enter a maximum flat price: "))
dummy_df = dummy_df[(dummy_df['resale_price'] >= min_flat_price) & (dummy_df['resale_price'] <= max_flat_price)]
dummy_df = dummy_df['flat_type']
flat_types_available = dummy_df.drop_duplicates()
flat_types_available = flat_types_available.reset_index(drop=True)
print(flat_types_available)
```

[image]

Comment: What did the index ever do to you that you want it gone so badly? Anyway you can use `print(df.to_string(index=False))`

Comment: Lol thank you!  Just had to follow the exact output indicated in the school document!